# linux find command + delete all snapshot files except last 5 ordered by date

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

under `/zookeeper/version-2` , we have many zookeeper snapshot files

```
.
.
.

-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333240 Aug  3 14:51 snapshot.5d00011991
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333240 Aug  3 14:53 snapshot.5d00011992
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333240 Aug  3 14:56 snapshot.5d00011993
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333235 Aug  4 06:18 snapshot.5d0001e0b4
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495326760 Aug  5 11:54 snapshot.5d0003660f
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495335787 Aug  6 08:39 snapshot.5d00047faf
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495335268 Aug  7 01:26 snapshot.5d000563eb
```

I need to sort the **snapshot** files by date and delete all **snapshot** files except recent 5 snapshot files.
all other files that are not snapshot should be remained

I created the following cli syntax in order to remove all **snapshot** files except last 5 ordered by date , but not know exactly how to integrate it with `find` command

```
ls -ltr zookeeper/version-2 | grep snapshot  | head -n -5 | xargs rm -f
```

note  the final target is to set the find command in cron job ( crontab )

*example of expected output*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333240 Aug  3 14:56 snapshot.5d00011993
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495333235 Aug  4 06:18 snapshot.5d0001e0b4
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495326760 Aug  5 11:54 snapshot.5d0003660f
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495335787 Aug  6 08:39 snapshot.5d00047faf
-rw-r--r-- 1 zookeeper hadoop 495335268 Aug  7 01:26 snapshot.5d000563eb
```

Comment: So what's the question? Surely you must already see that you don't want `-l`, and could simplify to `rm $(ls -tr zookeeper/version-2/snapshot* | head -n5)` if you are sure you will never have whitespace or other special characters in the file name. Why do you want `find` now?

Comment: Why do you need to integrate it with the `find` command? Don't you know exactly where the snapshot files are located?

Comment: @Kusalananda, the problem is not where they are located but how they are used. IMHO it's not wise to remove them directly (with `rm`)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm not sure I understand. What is it with their current command that requires the additional use of `find`? The only issue I see with their pipeline, apart from requiring "nice" pathnames, is that it's using `ls` with `-l`.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think I see what you're saying. It's not that the issue is with `rm` though, but with zookeeper getting confused by files disappearing.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the idea is these snapshots may be in use by hadoop cluster in this moment. That's the reason there is special command :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove directly zookeeper snapshots may have unpredictable results for the hadoop cluster. There is specific command for this purpose:

```
zkCleanup.sh -n 5
```

Comment: the problem is that cli also remove the logs , but I want to remove only the snapshot , and remained the zoo logs

Comment: @yael, make backup copy of logs in dedicated directory and then remove snapshots

Comment: @yael, for the record you need only new logs, old can be removed because logs are converted (when they become big) from zookeeper to snapshots.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh`:

```
rm -f /zookeeper/version-2/snapshort.*(N.om[6,-1])
```

Where `om` `o`rders by `m`odification time (newest first like `ls -t` does), `.` restricts to *regular* files, `N` enables `N`ullglob, `[6,-1]` selects the 6th to last. If there are fewer than 6 files, `rm -f` is called without argument, but should not complain about it.

Comment: nice but we not have zsh in RHEL version

Comment: @yael, I'm pretty sure RHEL has a zsh package in its core repositories.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Ok, those (correct) comments were too much for me. Thanks. I dug into this. It's actually harder than I thought. Solved at least the 'no-files found' case. The grep generates a non-zero returncode if nothing is found. Cheers.

```
find /zookeeper/version-2 -type f -name 'snapshot.*' | grep . | \
xargs -I% -n1 bash -c 'ls -tr "$@" || exit 255' _ % | head -n -5 | \
xargs echo rm -v
```

Remove the echo to really remove them.

And yes: I think it's ugly too.

Comment: Note that this may call `ls -tr` multiple times with batches of found files. It is therefore not certain that you remove all but the five most recent.

Comment: This will just run `ls -tr` of the current directory as many times as you have snapshot files. It doesn't list snapshot files, so you are likely to remove completely unrelated files.

Comment: I had misunderstood this, and tested on my system where `/zookeeper/version-2 ` doesn't exist, so this ended up removing files in my current directory. So I deleted the answer as dangerous, but that wasn't fair: it will kinda work if the directory you pass to find does exist. It's still problematic because of the issue Kusalananda pointed out, but at least it's not as dangerous as I had though. Sorry!

Comment: During discussions with @terdon, we also realized that the pipeline would remove files from the current directory if `find` fails to find any files (even if the search path exists). You could mitigate this by using `xargs` with `-r`.